# Custom Slider Android

Tags: android, user-interface, bluetooth, controller, slider

I'm developing a remote controller in Android to my project, that will control a toy car via bluetooth and I need to make a custom slider, the default value(0) must be in the center, something like this:

[image]

I don't know if it's really need to be a slider, ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a regular seekbar and rotate it 90 degrees and set custom drawables to look like in your picture.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="90" />
```

And to acquaire zero value at center you can use simple calculation, something like this:

```
private int getSeekbarValue(){
    SeekBar bar;
    return (bar.getProgress() - seekbar min value) * (max output value - min output value) / (seekbar max value - seekbar min value) + min output value;
}
```